# How to prove that $\mathbb{R}^2$ cartesian product of open intervals in $\mathbb{R}^1$ is also open?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

Having interval $(-1, 1)\in \mathbb{R}^1$ it is logical and intuitive that cartesian product of this interval in  $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. $(-1, 1)\times(-1, 1)$ is also open.

But how can one prove that via the simplest way?

Comment: It is per definition of the product topology open since $(-1,1)$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Then the question is: Which topology do you endow $\Bbb R^2$ with? If you take the product topology, this follows basically from the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $(x,y)\in (-1,1)^2$. Then, consider the ball $B((x,y),\dfrac{r}{2})$ where $r=\min\{|x+1|,|x-1|,|y+1|,|y-1|\}$. Then for any $(a,b)\in B((x,y),\dfrac{r}{2})$ we have that $(a,b)\in(-1,1)^2$. Hence $B((x,y),\dfrac{r}{2})\subseteq (-1,1)^2$.

Note that the metric used is the Euclidean metric.